# Use openlayers extent in angular 6 to get its center.

Tags: angular6, openlayers

I use openlayers 5 in angular 6 .

I import the openlayers extent like so in my file

```
import * as Extent from 'ol/extent.js'; 

extent: Extent;
```

and then I get some features and try to get their center by getting their geometry, then their extent and then the center. The code is

```
let features = this.vectorsource.getFeatures();
this.extent = new Extent({}); 
features.forEach((item) => { 
  var aa = item.getGeometry().getExtent();
  var oo = this.extent.getCenter(aa);
  console.log("The center is :  "+ oo); 
});
```

I get the following error

> `ERROR TypeError: ol_extent_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__ is not a
>   constructor`

How can I fix this, so I get the center?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ol.extent is a namespace, not a constructor.  If you have imported as Extent the code would be

```
let features = this.vectorsource.getFeatures();
features.forEach((item) => { 
  var aa = item.getGeometry().getExtent();
  var oo = Extent.getCenter(aa);
  console.log("The center is :  "+ oo); 
});
```